# Use useState value in useEffect without making the state update useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm working on a function that manages a string array based on object keys. Let's say it looks like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FieldContext from "../contexts/FieldContext";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
// the `data` array gets changed every second due to a WebSocket, in case that's important
const [data, setData] = useState({ foo: [], bar: [] });
const [connections, setConnections] = useState(["conn1", "conn2"]);

const { checkedFields } = useContext(FieldContext); // ["foo", "moo"];

useEffect(() => {
  setConnections(prevConnections => {
    // The code below does the following: 
    // Loop through the temporary connections (which is a copy of checkedFields)
    // A. if `tempConn` is a key in the `data` object, push the name with `update_` prefix to the `_conns` array
    // B. If not, just push it without a prefix to the `_conns` array
    // Since the `checkedFields` array is ["foo", "moo"], the first element will get the prefix,
    // the other won't and will just get pushed.
    let _tempConns = [...checkedFields];
    let _conns = [];
    _tempConns.forEach(tempConn => {
      if (data[tempConn] !== undefined) _conns.push(`update_${tempConn}`);
      else _conns.push(tempConn);
    });
    return _conns;
  });
}, [checkedFields]);

// the websocket hook
useEffect(() => {
  const _socket = io(WS_URI);
  _socket.on("info", data => {
    // some magic happens here to add to the `data` object which is not important for this question
  });
  setSocket(_socket);
}, [])
```

I get the following warning while using this hook: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'data'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`. Which I understand, but if I include `data` in the dependency array, I get an enormous amount of unnecessary updates. How do I prevent that from happening? *(without using `// eslint-disable-next-line` please)*

Comment: do you have any other effect that would need to run when `data` changes?

Comment: yes, I got one, this is just demo code

Comment: Hello. With your update (websocket) i found a similar example. And it's using Reducer ^^: https://adamrackis.dev/state-and-use-reducer/ . Hope it'll be usefull

Comment: i was going to suggest `const data = useRef({foo: [], bar: [] })` with the socket updating the `data.current` property values directly... but if you want other effects to run when the reference for `data` changes, then it's not feasible and wont work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not only missing `data` from the dependency array of `useEffect` hook but you are also missing `setConnections()` function from the dependency array.

You can use `useReducer` hook to move the state update logic out of the `useEffect` hook.

```
const initialState = {
   data: { foo: [], bar: [] },
   connections: ["conn1", "conn2"]
} 

const reducerFunc = (state, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
       case 'UPDATE_CONNECTIONS':
          let _tempConns = [...action.checkedFields];
          let _conns = [];
          _tempConns.forEach(tempConn => {
              if (state.data[tempConn] !== undefined) _conns.push(`update_${tempConn}`);
              else _conns.push(tempConn);
          });
          return { ...state, connections: _conns };
        default: 
          return state;
   }
};

const [myState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerFunc, initialState);

const { checkedFields } = useContext(FieldContext); // ["foo", "moo"];

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CONNECTIONS', payload: checkedFields });
}, [checkedFields]);
```

Since React makes sure that `dispatch` function won't change, you can omit it from `useEffect` hook's dependency array.

For details on how to use `useReducer` hook, see folowing links:

- [useReducer Hook - React Hooks Cheatsheet](https://react-hooks-cheatsheet.com/usereducer)
- [useReducer Hook - React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: I do not understand reducer at all, so I have no clue how to manage this..

Comment: i have added the implementation of reducer function which should give you an idea of how to implement `useReducer` hook in your code

Answer (score 1):

Could try with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) if you can get away with the following in your websocket and there are no other `useEffect`s counting on the `data` reference

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

```
// make `data` a ref object
// Pitfall: any changes to `data.current` will NOT be tracked 
const data = useRef({ foo: [], bar: [] })


// the websocket hook
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  _socket.on("info", data => {
    ...
    // update properties on `data.current`
    data.current.foo = 'some new value'
    data.current.bar = 'anoher new value;
  });
  
  ...
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  setConnections(prevConnections => {
    ... 
    // reference data value from data.current
    const data = data.current

    ...
    return _conns;
  });
}, [checkedFields])
```

Comment: aren't you missing `data` and `setConnection()` in `useEffect` hook's dependency array?

Comment: @Yousaf useRef doesn't require dependency to be added in useEffect

Answer (score 0):

With your update, it seems that your socket never close.
If your component unmount / remount, you add a new socket on background.
And then on every updates, it fire all previous sockets.

Your socket hook should return a close socket function. (I guess, I never use socket directly)

```
  useEffect(() => {
  const _socket = io(WS_URI);
  _socket.on("info", data => {
    // some magic happens here to add to the `data` object which is not important for this question
  });
  setSocket(_socket);
  return () => {_socket.close();}
}, [])
```

(That's not the response of your answer but it can help :) )

Comment: I update my answer to be more precise. You'll have a memory leak only on unmount / remount ;). It can be really weird haha